# Pyspark: - Failed to initialise Spark session (Another SparkContext is being constructed)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

HI I am pretty new to spark i want to use pyspark to stream data from Kafka to mongo but i am not able to run pyspark. and every-time i run it on terminal it gives following error.I have deleted and reinstalled Java Kafka Scala and pyspark multiple times but unable to resolve it found few methods tried to do them but unable to get it resolved. If it run spark shell on terminal it works while giving warning

[image: Here is image of complete error]

and here is my pyspark and java version that i have right now:

[image: version info]

If you have solution on this please help me with it i have stuck a wall with this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys if you are facing the same issue you can do what i did.

1. i removed all spark and scala and java also pyspark
2. reinstall `brew reinstall apache-spark`
3. after that you cam use `pyspark` or `spark-shell` to run it again.

it worked for me because my spark-shell was also giving an error so reinstalling apache spark was able to solve it.